# Integrating a Simple Piecewise Function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

If I define

```
f[x_]:=If[x<0,-1,1]
```

and then integrate,say

```
Integrate[f[x],{x,-3,7}]
```

I get what I expect, namely 4.

But if I do the same thing with a different function

```
f[x_] := If[x < -1, 1/(2x^2), If[x > 1, 1/(2x^2), 0]]
```

and if I then integrate

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, -3, 7}]
```

I do not, as expected, get 16/21; instead I just get an expression consisting of an integral sign with -3 and 7 at the limits, followed by the definition of f just as I typed it above (with all the If statements, etc) and then a dx.

I can of course break the integral into two parts, either of which Mathematica handles perfectly well.  But how do I get it to evaluate this expression without my manual intervention?

Comment: Instead of using `If`, construct the function using `Piecewise`.

Comment: Using `Piecewise` is better, but an alternative is `Integrate[PiecewiseExpand@f[x], {x, -3, 7}]`, which converts the function to `Piecewise`.

Comment: @Szabolcs:  I hadn't known about Piecewise, and apparently the very old version of Mathematica that I use (4.1.0.0) doesn't know about it either.  Of course I shouldn't expect that others will tailor their answers to my ancient software, so I do thank you for the suggestion, though it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Piecewise` to define your piecewise functions. For example your second example could be defined as follows:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1/(2 x^2), Abs[x] > 1}, {0, True}}]
```

Integration:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, -3, 7}]
```

yields 16/21

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematica 9.0 the second integral evaluates to 16/21...

Comment: Thanks for this info.  Maybe it's time to upgrade.